# For the QFT path integral action for a pair of sources and sinks $W_{ij}(J_1,J_2)$, is $W_{12} = W_{21}$ ever NOT exactly upheld?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

The path integral's action $W_{ij}$ as a function of a pair of sources and sinks $J = J_1 + J_2$ can be written

$$W_{ij} = -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^4k}{(2 \pi)^4}J_j^*(k)\frac{1}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}J_i(k)$$

so that for $J_1 + J_2 := \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x_1}) + \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x_2})$, we have $W_{12} = W_{21}$.

I have three related questions:

1. Are there any (physically reasonable) $J_l(k)$'s that would make $W_{12} \neq W_{21}$? If so, how does that play out in real life -- does it lead to any physically meaningful behavioral changes?
2. Were any approximations made in the derivation of $W_{ij}$ that would make $W_{12}=W_{21}$ **not** an exact result?
3. Is there any other case you know of where this equality may (or may not) be broken in an interesting or instructive way?

Comment: What happened to the complex conjugation?

Comment: @Qmechanic are you referring to the line "so that for $J_1 + J_2$ ..."? I can see how that wording might be confusing.

Comment: I think Qmechanic was trying to hint that the answer to your question is in the question itself. The formula for $W_{ij}$ that you've written satisfies the identity $W_{ij} = W_{ji}^{*}$. So, obviously, $W_{ij} = W_{ji}$ when $W_{ij}$ is real.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov but, correct me if I'm wrong, a real-valued J(x) can yield a complex-valued J(k). Is there a global phase shared by $J_1$ and $J_2$ that can be fixed to make them real-valued, or some other method of preserving $W_{ij} = W_{ji}^*$? There must be, since the basis doesn't matter...